# I want to remove unnecessary blank spaces adding between tags

Tags: html, css

I am not adding any blank spaces explicitly in code. But while running it in browser some blank spaces are adding automatically. I don't know why it happening.

Below is the code,

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:3%" >
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <label for="company-name" class="control-label">Forecast Time (Hrs):</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <input type="numbersOnly" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($forecasttime); ?>" id="txt_editorderforecasttime" name="orderforecasttime"  />
   </div>
</div>
```

But when I run it in browser(am using safari, even in chrome am getting the same while inspecting,

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:3%" >
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      "                         "
      <label for="company-name" class="control-label">Forecast Time (Hrs):</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <input type="numbersOnly" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($forecasttime); ?>" id="txt_editorderforecasttime" name="orderforecasttime"  />
   </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know the reason why it is happening .

Thanks in advance

Comment: add your full code with css

Comment: As a wild guess, I would assume your editor is adding those spaces when you add a newline when editing your markup.

Comment: thank u all for ur consideration. it is resolved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you put your content between your tags after hitting enter button (to beautify your code). This is pure editor problem and has noting to do with HTML or code script.

Comment: Yeah I corrected it and now it is working properly. Thanks :)